# accessing Gmail on Haiku alpha builds

Tags: gmail, ssl, haiku

I use the MDR in BeOS R5 to send/receive through Gmail no problem, but on Haiku it says, "No reply."  Is it because there are no SSL options in the e-mail prefs under Haiku?  How do I enable them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It now works on the latest nightly (SSL is an option in the prefs.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Gmail only accepts SSL connections to its IMAP and POP3 services.

If the mail client doesn't support SSL, a workaround might be to install [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) (if you can get it to run on Haiku, or have a spare Linux/Windows box), then add a service like this, to `stunnel.conf`:

```
[gmail-imap]
accept = 143
client = yes
connect = imap.gmail.com:993
```

Then set up MDR to connect to `localhost:143` without SSL. (Of course, replace `localhost` with the address of your `stunnel` server, if that's different.)

Comment: That's the weird thing--the MDR for BeOS is the same one that ended up in the Haiku branch, and Haiku comes with OpenSSL, so it should actually support it.  I'll look into stunnel though, thanks for the lead.

Comment: I don't think stunnel is available on haiku, nor do I have the skills to get it to compile.  I also don't have a spare box.  :|